# Vanishing permissions entries SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, permissions

I have noticed that when I add permissions to my 2013 page, the individual doesn't show up in the permissions list.  Meaning I click "grant permissions" and add Joe Smith.  The email goes out to Joe and I get a copy stating that he has been added, but "Joe Smith" doesn't show up anywhere on the permissions list.  I have refreshed several times.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are likely adding him to a group. Use the "check permissions" option in the advanced permissions area to see which group he is in. The list of names often does not contain all users if there are many placed in groups.

Comment: Thank you! I have not selected any group to add him to, I just tried to add him directly to the site.  Would SP automatically add him to a group instead of the site? If so how do I control what groups he is added to? When I check permissions I see that he is added to some groups.

Comment: Yes, new in 2013. The share/invite options add them to a group by default, use the "Show Options" link to see and select which group.

Comment: I don't see a "show options" link?

Comment: Which permissions button are you clicking? There are about 14 different ways, some of them don't show that option.

Comment: I finally found it and the group with your help @Aboba!  I am advances on 2010 permissions but apparently some critical defaults have changed for 2013.  How can I get an individual added outside of a group in 2013? (I'll be taking tutorials to catch up)